# How can my webserver send a signal (including data) to my local running applications

Tags: c#, php, networking, web

I want to have a website *(on the internet)* build in `PHP` and a application *(in C#)* installed on my personal computer. And for example when I click on a button *(from website)*, the application pop-up a message.

A solution that when I click on that button a commands *(text)* is saved in database and my application check that database *(on the internet)* every 2 seconds, if there is a new command.

But I think this solution is worst in performance, in most cases the application will run `12h/day`, and maybe 5 clicks will be on that button.

Another solution would be after I click on the button *(from website)*, go on my application and click some button to find if there is new commands; but I don`t like this solution.

I want a solution that after I open the application I don`t have anything to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two options if you don't have a channel from server to client:

1. Using polling (this is what you described)
2. Using some kind of the [`Comet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) web application model

Since the server has no connection to the client, it can't send a signal notifing the client new data is ready to go. This is a well known problem in terms of web applications that feature live updates (such as an chat application). The [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) web application model is one of the models that big sites like facebook or twitter are using to adress this problem.